# mediaCodec android- How to do decoding encoding from buffer to buffer

Tags: android, encoding, decoding, android-mediacodec, transcode

I want to decode and then encode a video file. The example I found on bigflakes is using the Inputsurface for decoding. I want to directly provide the decoded data to the encoder as input. I am getting error that the output buffer from decoder is null, when I provide that as input to the encoder. 
Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to decode data to a ByteBuffer and then pass that to the encoder?  That only works on certain devices; many will not accept their own output as input.  This is why DecodeEditEncode uses a Surface.

Comment: Thanks @fadden Thats what I was trying. I tried the DecodeEditEncodeTest - what output should I get there ?

Comment: Another quick question : In EncodeANdMuxTest - If I want to provide my video file as input, how should that be done. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: These programs were written as part of an automated test framework, not intended to be stand-alone tools, so all input is generated and all output is checked and discarded.  Adapting it to work with "real" I/O is left as an exercise for the reader, but you can find some examples in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Thanks @fadden. I will look into the example.

Comment: @fadden. I looked into the grafika app. Very nice. But I still don't see any example of providing your own video for encoding and muxing. Can you please point to the right one. All I want to do is provide my own video for encoding/ edit it / and write it back as output in mp4 format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any pointers on it ?