# MediaCodec.configure fails with IllegalStateException for 1080p videos

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I've been using grafika's [MoviePlayer](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MoviePlayer.java) and bigFlake's [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt) to implement a seeking and extract frame feature in our app. These work fine for most of our user, however some of them encounter a `IllegalStateException` on `MediaCodec.configure` when setting up the `ExtractMpegFramesTest` (this happens on Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, Samsung Galaxy J7, Samsung Galaxy A5, Huawei Ascend G7). The relevant code is as the following:

`MoviePlayer`

```
public void prepareResources() throws IOException {
    // The MediaExtractor error messages aren't very useful.  Check to see if the input
    // file exists so we can throw a better one if it's not there.
    if (!mSourceFile.canRead()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to read " + mSourceFile);
    }

    try {
        mExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        mExtractor.setDataSource(mSourceFile.toString());
        mTrackIndex = selectTrack(mExtractor);
        if (mTrackIndex < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No video track found in " + mSourceFile);
        }
        mExtractor.selectTrack(mTrackIndex);

        MediaFormat format = mExtractor.getTrackFormat(mTrackIndex);

        // Create a MediaCodec decoder, and configure it with the MediaFormat from the
        // extractor.  It's very important to use the format from the extractor because
        // it contains a copy of the CSD-0/CSD-1 codec-specific data chunks.
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        mDecoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        mDecoder.configure(format, mOutputSurface, null, 0);
        mDecoder.start();
        mDecoderInputBuffers = mDecoder.getInputBuffers();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`ExtractMpegFramesTest`

```
private void extractMpegFrames() throws IOException {
    MediaCodec decoder = null;
    CodecOutputSurface outputSurface = null;
    MediaExtractor extractor = null;
    /*int saveWidth = 640;
    int saveHeight = 480;*/

    try {
        long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        File inputFile = new File(mInputVideoPath);   // must be an absolute path
        // The MediaExtractor error messages aren't very useful.  Check to see if the input
        // file exists so we can throw a better one if it's not there.
        if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to read " + inputFile);
        }

        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        extractor.setDataSource(inputFile.toString());
        int trackIndex = selectTrack(extractor);
        if (trackIndex < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No video track found in " + inputFile);
        }
        extractor.selectTrack(trackIndex);

        MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex);
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Video size is " + format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH) + "x" +
                    format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT));
        }

        // Could use width/height from the MediaFormat to get full-size frames.
        outputSurface = new CodecOutputSurface(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH), format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT));

        // Create a MediaCodec decoder, and configure it with the MediaFormat from the
        // extractor.  It's very important to use the format from the extractor because
        // it contains a copy of the CSD-0/CSD-1 codec-specific data chunks.
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        decoder.configure(format, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0); //fails right here
        decoder.start();

        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Timber.d("extractMpegFrames(): FRAME_EXTRACT setup in: %d millis", (end1-start1));

        long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        doExtract(extractor, trackIndex, decoder, outputSurface);
        long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Timber.d("extractMpegFrames(): FRAME_EXTRACT doExtract in: %d millis", (end2-start2));
    } finally {
        // release everything we grabbed
        if (outputSurface != null) {
            outputSurface.release();
            outputSurface = null;
        }
        if (decoder != null) {
            decoder.stop();
            decoder.release();
            decoder = null;
        }
        if (extractor != null) {
            extractor.release();
            extractor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243175/1602807), however what I don't understand is why `MediaCodec` can be configured OK in `MoviePlayer` (the video runs just fine) but it fails in `ExtractMpegFramesTest`. At first, I think the device has some issues with the OpenGL set up, but it turn out to be MediaCodec problem.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** After obtaining a Galaxy S4 mini testing device, I've been able to get a much more helpful log:

```
D/MoviePlayer: Extractor selected track 0 (video/avc): {max-input-size=1572864, height=1080, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=20,capacity=20], width=1920, durationUs=5131211, csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=9,capacity=9], mime=video/avc, isDMCMMExtractor=1}
D/MoviePlayer: Video size is 1920x1080
D/MoviePlayer: Extractor selected track 0 (video/avc): {max-input-size=1572864, height=1080, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=20,capacity=20], width=1920, durationUs=5131211, csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=9,capacity=9], mime=video/avc, isDMCMMExtractor=1}
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
E/ACodec:  configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 3283
E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -38
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -38)
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:262)
W/System.err:     at co.test.testing.player.MoviePlayer.prepareResources(MoviePlayer.java:237)
W/System.err:     at co.test.testing.activities.VideoActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoActivity.java:276)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:602)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:94)
W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:891)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2201)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the codec info retrieved from devices having this problem:

- OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc
- OMX.SEC.avc.enc
- OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder

The strange thing is the Galaxy S4 mini can handle 720p videos just fine, it's just having problem with 1080p videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here to answer my own question again:

- Firstly, why I can't extract frame with `ExtractMpegFramesTest` after using `MoviePlayer` to display videos:

  It appears that some devices can't handle 2 instances of `MediaCodec` at the same time for high res videos (>720p in the case of the Galaxy S4 mini) so you have to properly release one instance of `MediaCodec` before starting the other one, something like this:

  ```
  public void releaseResources() {
      // release everything we grabbed
      if (mDecoder != null) {
          try {
              mDecoder.stop();
              mDecoder.release();
              mDecoder = null;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Timber.d("releaseResources(): message %s cause %s", e.getMessage(),  e.getCause());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      if (mExtractor != null) {
          try {
              mExtractor.release();
              mExtractor = null;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Timber.d("releaseResources(): message %s cause %s", e.getMessage(),  e.getCause());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Secondly, why the `MoviePlayer` fails to configure for 1080p videos. In my case, since I start this activity from a media picker activity with a `VideoView` for preview which has a `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()` registered to detect faulty video. The problem is the `onError()` callback has some really weird behavior on the Galaxy S4 mini while it work perfectly fine on my development devices. My wild guess this `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()` leaves the `MediaCodec` in a bad state that cause a lot of headache later on.

  So the solution is to set a blank `OnErrorListener()` and properly release the `VideoView` before doing anything else with `MediaCodec`. Something like this:

  ```
  mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
              return true;
          }
  });
  .....
  mVideoView.stopPlayback();
  doOtherThingWithMediaCodec();
  ```

This explain a lot of weird thing that happen on different devices. I hope this help someone else debug their app.

Comment: Hi, I need both objects for same time for example- Encoder & Decoder in that what should I do?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901345/mediacodec-android-how-to-do-decoding-encoding-from-buffer-to-buffer). In short, as per my experiment, only some devices can work with multiple instances of MediaCodec. The `DecodeEditEncodeTest` mentioned above can be found [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Comment: no Vxh it does not work as per my program. you can see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298769/video-compression-issue-in-samsung-s5-device